# How to reduce loading time for web pages with lots of scripts

Tags: javascript, web, meteor, loading

I am trying to develop a website using meteors. My problem is that the website takes a really long time to load (> 2-3 min). When I checked the network tab in "inspect elements" I see that majority of the load time comes from scripts in the folder "/packages/".

I'm not sure if this is abnormal but I have about 90 lines of code that calls for client side scripts most of them are less than 300b.

I am inexperienced with web development so I'm not sure how to improve this, can someone tell me what the problem is and how would I solve it?

Comment: You need to bisectinate your code until you find the part that is the culprit, then post that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Merge multiple scrips into single file - most important in your case to minimize number of HTTP requests
- Minify/compress JS file
- Serve this file from CDN

Tools

- [node-minify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-minify)
- [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) - essentially you can serve all your pages through them and they will do optimizations for you

Answer (score 2):

simply, just include your script files and imports at the bottom of the body tag.
this way the html and css will load first and JavaScripts will load later in the background , making it faster